# Ant Javac Compilation Output

Tags: java, jsf, ant

I am trying to compile java files from a java program using `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac` and to print its output on screen.

See the below code snippet for your reference,

```
Javac javaCompile = (Javac) webServiceProject.createTask("javac");
javaCompile.setSrcdir("D:\\Java\\src");
javaCompile.setDestdir("D:\\Java\\classes");
try{
    javaCompile.execute();
}catch (BuildException buildException){
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(buildException.getMessage());
    message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

When i compile the files with the above code and if any compilation error exists, i get a message `"Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details."`.

I don't know how to retrieve the compilation error and show it as an output on screen.
Can anyone suggest how to retrieve it?

Comment: You are compiling Java classes from your JSF application? Don't do that :-) Seriously, if you do such a monstrous thing, you should decouple your layers. Using a compiler does not belong to the concerns a JSF app should know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code did the trick and this retrieved me the compiler error.

```
Javac javaCompile = (Javac) webServiceProject.createTask("javac");
javaCompile.createCompilerArg().setValue("-Xstdout");
String filePath = basePath + "resources" + File.separator
        + "errorlog.log";
javaCompile.createCompilerArg().setFile(new File(filePath));
javaCompile.setNowarn(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the issue of whether you *should* be compiling code in a JSF application ...

I believe that Ant sends compilation output to the logger.  So to get hold of it, you will need to configure the logger to send the relevant log events to a file ... or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the build.compiler setting. Ant was having trouble finding the compiler I had specified, "org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter" - changing it to "modern" allowed me to compile.

This was tricky to track down. I'm not sure why there was no output.